# Retrieving information stored in other sessions with gae-sessions

Tags: python, google-app-engine, session

I made a simple login system with [gae-sessions](https://github.com/dound/gae-sessions/wiki), and I want to show a logged in user how many users are logged in and who they are.

To count the number of people logged in, when I log a user in I immediately save the session to the datastore with save(persist_even_if_using_cookie=True). Then I use SessionModel.all().count() to retrieve the number of logged in accounts.

I'm having trouble retrieving information on other sessions though. I'm not sure how to do it. I tried this:

```
logged_in = []
for activesession in SessionModel.all():
    logged_in.append(activesession['user'])
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: 'SessionModel' object is unsubscriptable
```

I also tried activesession.get('user'), but it results in another error:

```
BadKeyError: Invalid string key user.
```

How can I do this?

Comment: why can't you just say len(SessionModel.all()) and forget about duplicate sessions ?

Comment: Are you referring to the piece of code to get the number of sessions in the datastore? Doesn't count() return a integer just like len()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Session object and the SessionModel are separate from each other.  SessionModel only stores the contents of the session, it can't be read from like a Session object.

I have a feeling that this is a bad idea, and you should find another way to store/retrieve the list of logged in users. This method may return expired sessions that haven't been deleted yet, and will probably be really slow.

The method you want to call is __decode_data.  I think something like this will work:

```
for activesession in SessionModel.all():
    data = Session._Session__decode_data(activesession.pdump)
    logged_in.append(data['user'])
```

Comment: Is the returning of expired sessions the only problem with my solution? What if I call delete_expired_sessions() every time this particular piece of code is called?

Comment: Depending on how many session you have the delete_expired_sessions function can take a while to execute.  Then iterating through the list of remaining sessions could take a while, and decoding all the session objects just to get one property is a lot of cpu work. I would only do this if it's something that is only rarely used by admins.  If it's done for every user I'd find another way.